# ruby on rails cannot use permit.require

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to build a simple blog on `rails 5`. I have created a post model:

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "title"
  t.text "body"
  t.integer "category_id"
  t.integer "author_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

And my controller methods:

```
def new
    @post = Post.new
    @categories = Category.all

end

def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    if @post_save
        redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Post has benn created"
    else
        render "new"
    end

end

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :category_id)
end
```

When I try to add another post via an html form nothing happens. The page with the form is reloaded and the post itself is not saved. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because there's a typo in the `create` method

`@post_save` must be `@post.save`

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)
  if @post.save
    redirect_to posts_path, :notice => "Post has been created"
  else
    render "new"
  end
end
```

Since `@post_save` is not defined, `else` block is evaluated and `new` page is rendered and nothing happens

Comment: Yes. That was my error. Now everything works fine. Thank you Igor!

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should also permit :author_id if you have such a field in your form. Because, as I understand, post belongs_to :author. That means author_id is mandatory in post creation.
And also, you have a typo, you should change "@post_save" => "@post.save!" (it was mentioned in earlier answer).